# Detect chinese (multibyte) character in the string

Tags: php, multibyte, cjk

```
$str = "This is a string containing 中文 characters. Some more characters - 中华人民共和国 ";
```

How do I detect chinese characters from this string and print the part which starts with the first character and ends with "-"? (it would be "中文 characters. Some more characters -").

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've solved this problem using preg_match and regular expressions:

```
$str = "This is a string containing 中文 characters. Some more characters - 中华人民共和国 ";

preg_match(/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+.*\-/u, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for this... curious, where is the ability to use \x{unicode#} documented?

Answer (score 0):

Is PHP storing this as Unicode? If so, at worst you could step through the string, character by character, until you hit those within the Chinese range.

Check this out too [PHP: Unicode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.unicode.php)

Comment: @Josh - if you follow boost's suggestion, to might like to also look at VonC's answer to this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode

Comment: @boost, yes, php is storing the string in unicode. But how do I accomplish it? I'm not very good in php.
@JV, thanks, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: if you do not convert it to NCR form, it has chance to corrupt the characters during transactions.