# PHP regex to to decipher English and Chinese characters

Tags: php, regex, cjk

I have a description which is in English and Chinese.

How would I go about using regex to say something like, if the line contains a Chinese character then do A, else do B ?

example here

```
电源: 110V/220W50-60HZ
功率:60W
光源:12V 150 W
尺寸:220x150x280mm
重量:2.3KG



Voltage : 110V/220W50-60HZ
Power : 60W
Bulb : 12V 150 W
Size : 220x150x280mm
Weight:2.3KG
```

Comment: If the encoding is Unicode, English letters are codes 0x0041 to 0x005B and 0061 to 007B and Chinese characters are codes 0x4E00 - 0x4FFF. Your regex could possibly check for character code matches.

Comment: Why not searching StackOverflow?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550950/detect-chinese-multibyte-character-in-the-string

Comment: Do you want to translate from English to Chinese, or differentiate between them through a regexp? I don't really get the 'disifer' part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chinese characters are within the range: `U+4E00..U+9FFF`

If your expreg extension has been built with Unicde support, `b\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}` is a good replacement for `[\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}]` (which was in the link Jens Struwe gave).

You can find most (all?) of Unicode ranges here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but maybe a good start would be split your description by line. Then, for each line, find whether it's Chinese or not, and run the appropriate regex. ;)