# prevent chinese character input using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

How can I prevent chinese character input using jquery?

```
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexp) {
       var check = false;
            return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
     },
   " Must contain only letters."
 );
```

This is how I check if the input is letters.

```
regex: /^\s*[a-zA-Z\s]+\s*$/
```

But How can I check the chinese character?

Comment: `/^\s*[a-zA-Z\s]+\s*$/` doesn't include Chinese characters in the first place.

Comment: Just Chinese or Korean+Japanese+Thai+Etc?

Comment: There was a similar question on this for visual basic, you may want to simply adapt the regex solution and port it to jQuery or PHP, whatever better suits your requirements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710518/strip-chinese-characters-from-a-string-vba

Comment: @DaveChen Actually just chinese is ok but its doent matter if Korean+Japanese+Thai is also blocked. Mainly chinese character

Comment: @minitech `/^\s*[a-zA-Z\s]+\s*$/` I used to check english letter only

Comment: There was a similar question 

[PHP regex to decipher English and Chinese characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882967/php-regex-to-to-decipher-english-and-chinese-characters)

Answer (score 4):

this maybe useful：

```
function isChn(str){
    return /^[\u4E00-\u9FA5]+$/.test(str);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yiqiang1314/CMv7E/

Comment: this is ok for checking the chinese words. However what I want is prevent chinese words. I dont know why my checking becomes , input must be chinese instead of blocking. my question is updated

Comment: function hasChn(str){
    return /[\u4E00-\u9FA5]+/.test(str);
}
//remove ^ and $.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with your Regular Expression - you are already preventing every character besides a-z and whitespace (and there are no Chinese characters within the range of a-z).  But, you've got a problem with the function logic.  As it's currently written, if the field is optional, Chinese characters will be allowed.  You should only skip the regexp test when it's optional *and* empty:

```
return (!value && this.optional(element)) || regexp.test(value);
```