# How to restrict Chinese characters in input fields?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to restrict the Chinese character in the input field, only show the number in the input field. But below coding cannot let me restrict the Chinese character. Hope someone can help me on how to solve the problem?

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  console.log(charCode);
  if (charCode > 31 &&
    (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" id="code" name="code" value="" title="code">
```

Comment: Why don't you use `type="number"` for this input field?

Comment: Because number can type "e"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848666/prevent-chinese-character-input-using-jquery do you think this can help?

Comment: Because e stands for exponential and this is a number. You have to validate if the number that's entered valid, if 2e2 is not a valid number then don't let the user continue with this number.

Comment: So I need to write function to restrict e right?

Comment: [This seems like the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704708/how-to-restrict-chinese-characters-in-a-textbox-using-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Make oninput() Trigger Only When Chinese Characters, Not IME Keystrokes, Are Entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893492/how-can-i-make-oninput-trigger-only-when-chinese-characters-not-ime-keystroke)

Comment: @Rajat Cannot also