# Recognize Identifiers in Chinese characters by using Lex/Yacc

Tags: lex, lexical-analysis

How can I use Lex/Yacc to recognize identifiers in Chinese characters?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean Lex (the lexer generator). Yacc is the parser generator.

According to [What's the complete range for Chinese characters in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/), most CJH characters fall in the `3400-9FFF` range.

According to http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html

> Arbitrary character. To match almost
>   any character, the operator character
>   . is the class of all characters
>   except newline. Escaping into octal is
>   possible although non-portable:
>
> ```
>                              [\40-\176]
> ```
>
> matches all printable characters in
>   the ASCII character set, from octal 40
>   (blank) to octal 176 (tilde).

So I would assume what you need is something like `[\32000-\117777]`.

Answer (score 1):

`Yacc` does not care about Chinese characters, but `lex` does: it is responsible for analyzing the input bytes (and characters) to recognize tokens.  However, Chinese characters generally are multibyte.  There are programs *like* `lex` which may support this, but they're not `lex`.  It has been discussed several times.

Further reading:

- [Adding utf-8 Encoding to Lex](https://www.w3.org/2005/03/23-lex-U)

> The standard lexical tokenizer, **`lex`** (or **`flex`**), does not accept multi-byte characters, and is thusly impractical for many modern languages. This document describes a mapping from regular expressions describing UTF-8 multi-byte characters to a regular expressions of single bytes.

- [Flex(lexer) support for unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611682/flexlexer-support-for-unicode) (2012/3/8)

  Answers point out how you can work around the limitation by using special cases of UTF-8 patterns.
- [Unicode Support in Flex](http://xcybercloud.blogspot.com/2009/04/unicode-support-in-flex.html) (2009/4/26)

  Essentially the same as the previous (but preceding, and a possible source for those comments)
- [How do I lex unicode characters in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659671/how-do-i-lex-unicode-characters-in-c)

  An answer lists some alternative implementations which *may* do that was asked here.