# flex(lexer) and unicode file input

Tags: unicode, utf-8, bison, flex-lexer

I know flex can only use utf-8.

Is there a way to take a unicode file(utf-16 LE) as input and convert it to utf-8 internally?

It receives a file name as input and opens and uses the Unicode file.

```
...
yyin = fopen("fname", "r");
yyparse();
fclose(yyin);
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "Unicode file", exactly?

Comment: Do you mean you want to take some other Unicode encoding, like UTF-32, and use it as the input?

Comment: Yes, it is. I want to use utf-16 as input.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way you can do it directly in flex. However, You could add a preprocessing step where you convert the input to UTF-8 and save it as a temporary file. Then you can pass the temporary file to the `fopen` instead of the original file.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9611682/3052438

Comment: Do you require Windows support other than via Mingw?

Comment: Yes. Windows support is required.
I use flex++, bison++ output in visual studio.
I can't use yy_scan_string because I can only use flex++ version2.3.8.
So I have to convert utf-16 to .l inside.