# detect cjk characters in a sentence using ruby!

Tags: ruby, regex

```
$str = "This is a string containing 中文 characters. Some more characters - 中华人民共和国 ";
```

How do I detect if there are chinese characters in this string but i have no idea how to do it.Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are not the way to go here. You should rather have code similar to the following (disclaimer: I'm not a Ruby programmer):

```
# coding: utf-8
str = "This is a string containing 中文 characters. Some more characters - 中华人民共和国 ";

str.each_char { |c|
  if c.ord >= 0x4E00 && c.ord <= 0x9FFF
    # found a chinese character - process it somehow.
    puts c
  end   
}
```

You're esentially checking for if the character is in the range of common Chinese characters in Unicode. This is not the complete range of *hanzi* (Chinese characters). If you need to detect rare or historic characters you'll simply have to add the ranges listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode) to the boolean check.