# find Chinese character using C# ??

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unicode, c#-3.0

I am working on C#

I have some values in an array .

```
Stirng [] values;
```

Some of the values inside array are in chinese value .

I have to put these values in Database.
 Before putting this in Database i want to find out which values are in Chinese.

So that i can create proper SQLString to Execute

```
check isChinese(String abc ){
    **Condition for chinese unicode** ???

    return true or false
}

____
if tovalue isChinese == true 
     SqlValue= N +" ' toValue ' "

else
    SqlValue= SqlValue

SqlQuery = SqlQuery + SqlValue
```

Comment: i would use a parameterized query instead of building up the string manually.

Comment: Definitely, definitely, definitely use parameterized SQL. Always.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088241/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-unicode-text-is-in-a-certain-language

Comment: I am new to C# so .please help me to check the chinese character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related question on how to do a character range check: [Is there a way to check whether unicode text is in a certain language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088241/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-unicode-text-is-in-a-certain-language)

The full range of the Chinese character set can be found here: [What's the complete range for Chinese characters in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode)

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey this is first time i am using C#, Can you explain me how to use all these.EVEN for your first LINK

`return text.IndexOfAny(c => c >= 0x20000 && c <= 0xFA2D);`

there is a error Lambda expression to type Char[] because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 0):

You have to save all the Chinese characters in an array (char[] or string[]).

Then call the function, and have it check if the parameter is in the array:

```
if (chineseletters.IndexOf(parameter) >= 0) {
  return "This is a Chinese character!";
} else return "This is not a Chinese character!";
```