# multi language validation in javascript using validate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

i work on project which contain English and Chinese language but i can't figure out how can i validation with validate.js in Chinese language.

from surfing i found one link which give these type facilities but unfortunate this link not working please give me reference or hint

https://github.com/chilijung/validate.js

thanks in advance

Comment: Please post what you tried so far and an example of what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may custom your own method.

> http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

So you may use Regalur Expression to validate Chinese and English.

> [How to validate both Chinese (unicode) and English name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377407/how-to-validate-both-chinese-unicode-and-english-name)

Comment: thanks for answer i don't want to validate it  with both language because client input language is only english,  but i want validation messages in both language