# Get xpath for div inside td tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tired a lot to get the xpath of the div which displays as "カーク商品掲載カタログ Online" on screen, but I'm not able to. The application is made using ZK framework hence it has random ID's.

```
<td z.type="Lic" id="z_mk_qr1" class="activeCatalogVersionTreeItem z-list-cell" z.zcls="z-list-cell" onmouseout="dragHoverClick( $e('z_mk_qr1'), event, true, null, 0);" onmouseover="dragHoverClick( $e('z_mk_qr1'), event, false, 'PerspectiveDND', 500);">
    <div id="z_mk_qr1!cave" class="z-list-cell-cnt z-overflow-hidden">カーク商品掲載カタログ Online
        <span id="z_mk_rr1" class="catalog-mnemonic-label z-label" z.zcls="z-label"> (STO-O)
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

I thought the xpath should be something like //div[contains(text(),'カーク商品掲載カタログ Online')], but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: try once with CSS selector: div#z_mk_qr1!cave otherwise using IDE find different locator values and use the same

Comment: "z_mk_qr1!cave" is a random id generated by zk framework. It would differ the next time the page is reloaded. So cannot use it.

Comment: try using below cssSelector `td.activeCatalogVersionTreeItem div.z-list-cell-cnt`

Comment: @SanchitKhera Have a look at this for matching text --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611839/how-to-check-if-xml-textnode-has-chinese-characters-with-regex-in-a-xslt

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj.. Thanks! It worked.

Comment: i will create a new answer and accept it to make this issue close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below cssSelector to identify the required element.

```
td.activeCatalogVersionTreeItem div.z-list-cell-cnt
```

Comment: In case I want to select the second td having this type of css, what can be done?

Comment: `td.activeCatalogVersionTreeItem:nth-child(2) div.z-list-cell-cnt`. use `nth-child()` selector to locate element based on position.

Answer (score 0):

You may use partial text match in this case as follows:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Online')]
```

Check the link below for more:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10342/how-to-find-element-using-contains-in-xpath