# Add '<br>' before chinese character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to add `<br>` before Chinese character if Chinese wording is combined with normal text.

```
<?php

$string = 'Hello World 自立合作社';

/*
this is what I tried:
preg_match('/\\p{Han}/u', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches)
*/

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World</br>自立合作社
```

Comment: Is it always a single line, or can `$string` be multi-line?

Comment: Maybe you can use regex?

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes always single line

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski your answer is correct but why you delete ?

Comment: @rusly It may not work that well.  I'll undelete it if you'd like it to remain.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes put it back i will mark as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surely not the best solution, but one approach would be to match a string of ASCII characters via `[\x00-\x7F]+` followed by a non-ASCII sequence (same pattern negated with `^`). It does not target Chinese specifically, but that is tricky owing to [the varied ranges of Chinese Unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode).

```
$string = 'Hello World 自立合作社';
// Capture ASCII sequence into $1 and non-ASCII into $2
echo preg_replace('/([\x00-\x7F]+)([^\x00-\x7F]+)/', '$1<br/>$2', $string);

// Prints:
// Hello World 
// 自立合作社
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/1kqpOx

Actually, here's an improved version that does specifically target Chinese characters via `\p{Han}`.  The `$2` capture also includes `\s` for whitespace.

```
// This matches any non-Chinese in $1 followed by Chinese (and whitespace) in $2
echo preg_replace('/([^\p{Han}]+)([\p{Han}\s]+)/', '$1<br/>$2', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am no Chinese but I hope this helps.

As you are using php you can use preg_replace with [look ahead construct](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). 
It will replace all white space characters (those before chinese character) with a <br>.

```
$string = 'Hello World 自立合作社';
$pattern = "/\\p{Z}(?=\\p{Han})/ui"; // matches a white space before Chinese character. 

$brStr = preg_replace($pattern, "<br>", $string);
echo $brStr;
```

I don't know will \p{Han} match all Chinese characters so checkout more info on unicode characters [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#block)

[May be this one will help too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode)

Hope this helps. Good luck! ;)