# What is the relationship between unicode/utf-8/utf-16 and my local encode GBK?

Tags: encode

I've noted that my text file on Windows(chinese version), when port to Ubuntu, turned garbled.
After more research, I know the default encode on Windows CN version is GBK, while on Ubuntu is utf-8, and `iconv` can do the encode translation, for example, from GBK to utf-8:

```
iconv -f gbk -t utf-8 input.txt > output.txt
```

But I am still confused by the relationship of these encode. What are they? what is the similarity and difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First it is not about the OS, but about the program you are using to read the file.

On a bare .txt, the program has to be able to guess the encoding, which is not always possible, but might work. On an html, encoding is given as metadata, so browsers don't need to do that.

Second, do you know ASCII? Do you see how it represents symbols via numbers? If not this is the first thing you [should learn now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Next, do you see the difference between Unicode and UTF-XXX? It must be clear to you that Unicode is just a map of numbers (code points) to glyphs (symbols, including Chinese characters, ASCII characters, Egyptian characters, etc.)

UTF-XXX on the other hand says, given a string of bytes, which Unicode numbers (code points) do they represent. Therefore, UTF-8 and UTF-16 are different efficient ways to represent Unicode.

As you may imagine, unlike ASCII, both UTF and GBK must allow more than one byte per character, since there are much more than 256 of them.

In GBK all characters are encoded as 1 or 2 bytes.
Since GBK is specialized for Chinese, it uses less bytes in average than UTF-XXX to represent a given Chinese text, and more for other languages.

In UTF-8 and 16, the number of bytes per glyph is variable, so you have to look at how many bytes are used for the Chinese code points.

In Unicode, Chinese glyphs are on the [following ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode). Then you have to look at how efficiently UTF-8 and UTF-16 represent those ranges.

According to Wikipedia articles on UTF-8 and UTF-16, the first and most common range for Chinese glyphs 4E00-9FFF is represented in UTF-8 as either 2 or 3 bytes, while in UTF-16 it is represented as 2 bytes. Therefore, if you are going to use lots of Chinese, UTF-16 might be more efficient. You also have to look into the other ranges to see how many bytes per character are used.

For portability, the best choice is UTF, since UTF can represent almost any possible character set, so it is more likely that viewers will have been programmed to decode it correctly. The size gain of GBK is not that large.

Comment: I've been reading your answer all through and over, thank you for give so expert an answer. To summarize(please review): Unicode is a universal multiple language encode; UTF serials are specific representation of unicode in computer; GBK is a specialized encode for Chinese that is not portable.

Comment: I think you got the idea right. Unicode is multi language and maps numbers to glyphs. UTF are ways to encode serialized Unicode numbers. GBK is portable, it is just that it is more likely that (non Chinese) people will write software that deals with UTF than GBK, because they can write a single software that deals with any language instead of just Chinese.