# Judge Python str include Chinese

Tags: python

I want to define a function , Checks if a string is contained in Chinese. For example, 
check_contain_chinese("中国"), it returns True. check_contain_chinese('xx中国'), it returns True, check_contain_chinese("xxx"), it return False. 
Could someone give me some advice ? I'm a freshman ..

Comment: [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode) will nudge you to correct direction, I hope.

Comment: if you can read Chinese, check this post http://blog.oasisfeng.com/2006/10/19/full-cjk-unicode-range/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for the range of unicode characters to find out if a character in string belongs to chinese characters or not. A google search tells me all chinese characters fall between `'\u4e00'` and `u'\u9fff'`. You may want to verify that yourself.

```
def check_contain_chinese(check_str):
    for ch in check_str.decode('utf-8'):
        if u'\u4e00' <= ch <= u'\u9fff':
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: It's for CJK, not for chinese

Answer (score 3):

All existing answers here confused the **CJK** (which represents Chinese, Japanese, and Korean) characters with **Han** characters(which only represents Chinese) characters.

It's easy tell whether a character is CJK but harder to tell whether a character is Chinese and the standard is changing, new characters are being added always.

But in practice, people usually use **u'\u4e00' - u'\u9fa5'** to check whether a character. CJK characters out of that range usually can not be displayed by common Chinese fonts.

Sometimes [CJK Radicals Supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2E80.pdf), [Bopomofo](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3100.pdf), [CJK Strokes](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U31C0.pdf) should also be treated as characters, and they are not even in the CJK Unified Ideographs('\u4e00'- u'\u9fff'), but they are common and important in the Chinese writing system.

Reference:

[CJK characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK)

[CJK Unified Ideographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs)

[Unihan Database Lookup](http://www.unicode.org/charts/unihan.html)

[GB 2312 to Unicode](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GUS/Unicode-UTF8simple-1.06/gb2312.txt)

[GB 12345 to Unicode](http://examples.oreilly.com/cjkvinfo/unicode/gb12345-90.txt)

Answer (score 2):

There is [six Unicode maps](http://www.khngai.com/chinese/charmap/tbluni.php?page=0) for Chinese characters. Just check if code of any character in your string fits the 0x4E00 - 0x9FFF interval:

```
>>> any(0x4E00 <= ord(x) <= 0x9FFF for x in u'xx中国')
1: True
>>> any(0x4E00 <= ord(x) <= 0x9FFF for x in u'xxx')
2: False
```

Comment: Those maps are also for CJK characters, not for chinese only