# RegEX request with chinese characters

Tags: regex

I have a strange REGEX Request.  I would like to clear out all of these chinese characters from my file.  Im already not good with regex, and I would like to do this using RegEx within visual studio find/replace (current document) if possible.

Basically the search string would be like this:
BEFORE

```
 <nomenclature name="sCharge_Account_String" value="Charge Account/ 收费帐户:"/>
```

AFTER

```
 <nomenclature name="sCharge_Account_String" value="Charge Account:"/>
```

So I want to clear everything between the "/" and the ":" but include the "/"

Comment: Apparently the topic is about searching Chinese characters, but reason given to close this topic is off topic which is about all non-ASCII characters. [This post](https://ayaka.shn.hk/hanregex) has a few good ways to achieve it. For example in **JS**, `[\p{Unified_Ideograph}\u3006\u3007][\ufe00-\ufe0f\u{e0100}-\u{e01ef}]?`, `[\u4e00-\u9fff\u3400-\u4dbf\u{20000}-\u{2a6df}\u{2a700}-\u{2ebef}\u{30000}-\u{323af}\ufa0e\ufa0f\ufa11\ufa13\ufa14\ufa1f\ufa21\ufa23\ufa24\ufa27\ufa28\ufa29\u3006\u3007][\ufe00-\ufe0f\u{e0100}-\u{e01ef}]?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information on unicode ranges for Chinese characters:
[What's the complete range for Chinese characters in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode)

Information on how to match unicode characters:
[Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

I'll leave the rest up to you since it's a simple question of implementation.

Comment: Thanks!  With your help in one of the links I was able to use this RegEx code in visual studio in Find/Replace  /[^\u0000-\u0080]+