# How to convert unicode to its original character in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I first tried typing in a Unicode character, encode it in UTF-8, and decode it back. Python happily gives back the original character.
I took a look at the encoded string, it is `b'\xe6\x88\x91'`. I don't understand what this is, it looks like 3 hex numbers.

Then I did some research and I found that the CJK set starts from 4E00, so now I want Python to show me what this character looks like. How do I do that? Do I need to convert 4E00 to the form of something like the one above?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text `b'\xe6\x88\x91'` is the **representation** of the bytes that are the utf-8 encoding of the unicode codepoint `\u6211` which is the character 我. So there is no need in converting something, other than to a unicode string with `.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: So to convert 4E00 to the original character, what should I do? I'm not sure what 4E00 is, I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode

Comment: Converting "4E00" to a character is a completely different question.

Comment: @Xufeng: what is your real problem? `'\u4E00'` is the unicode representation of chinese «one»: 一. To write this character to disk, you have to encode it, e.g. with UTF-8: `u'\u4E00'.encode('utf-8')` -> `b'\xe4\xb8\x80'`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to decode it using the UTF-8 encoding:

```
>>> print(b'\xe6\x88\x91'.decode('UTF-8'))
我
```

By decoding it you're turning the bytes (which is what `b'...'` is) into a Unicode string and that's how you can display / use the text.

Comment: The text given in the question isn't encoded in utf-8, it's encoded in windows-1252. Using the detect function in chardet will show this.

Comment: @DavidGreydanus: most likely not, the user already told us the encoding is UTF-8 and displaying the text as windows-1252 doesn't seem to return valid text.