# Multilingual website and CSS font families

Tags: css, fonts, multilingual

I have been googlying around now about this matter and I find few ways to do it. But what is the best way to do it.

I have website that has +10 different languages. Some languages need own font (chinese, japanese for example). Normal english and most western versions will use Google's Open Sans. But what about japanese etc. How should I do font-family declaration?

Like this putting all fonts in same declaration?

```
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, 'Microsoft Yahei', '微软雅黑', STXihei, '华文细黑', 'MS PGothic', sans-serif;
}
```

'Microsoft Yahei', '微软雅黑', STXihei, '华文细黑' are MS Gothic is japanese windows font.

Or separate them?
Of course this would mean lot of more css than just body (h1, h2, p...)

```
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body.chines {
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Microsoft Yahei', '微软雅黑', STXihei, '华文细黑', sans-serif;
}

body.japanese {
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'MS PGothic', sans-serif;
}
```

I'm using Compass/sass btw

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal different languages is to have different css file for different language, which reduces page load time and resources.

Secondly, the asterisk implies all elements.

```
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [unicode-range](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/unicode-range) you could use.
It is used to display a certain font for a range of specific characters.

[This might help you to find the range of characters you want to include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode).

Ideally you have to setup all the fonts you need once.
And through unicode-range the browser uses the font that contains that character, and nothing is unnecessarily downloaded.