# Regex literal for accepting names having non-english characters

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, internationalization

Below is the regex pattern literal in javascript for accepting the *firstname*, *middlename* and *lastname* from html `input` element. There is zero or one space in between.

`var regpat= /^[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\.\' \-]{2,15}\s?[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\.\' \-]{2,15}\s?[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\.\' \-]{2,15}$/;/`

> Inputs:
>
> first name is `優子`, last name is `白石`, in japanese
>
> first name is `瞿`, middle name is `秋`, last name is `白`, in chinese

1) Is this regex pattern complete to accept names having English characters?

2) How can this regex literal be enhanced to accept Chinese/Korean/Japanese characters sitting in Unicode BMP(plane 0) characters?

Note: [17 planes in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode))

Comment: You do know that even BMP includes many [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters) and [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) that need to be used with other characters, and that BMP may expands with Unicode update, right?

Comment: @Sheepy Relevant point is to know the CJK ranges. `var regpat= /^[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u4E00-\u9FFF\.\' \-]{2,15}\s?/;console.log(regpat. test('優子'));`

Comment: You are probably going to be interested in reading this: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names However to note the entire BMP plane is `\u0000-\uFFFF` (this does include the NULL character though). Would people named "Adèle" and "Élise" be permitted to use your form?

Comment: @overexchange Ok, the improved question is better.  But BMP Chinese is pretty incomplete - [陶](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_Tsao), a well known columnist and broadcaster in Hong Kong - has a name in the supplement plane.  Why do you want to limit to BMP?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What's the complete range for Chinese characters in Unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode).  Alternatively, wikipedia has a pretty up to date [CJK list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs).

Comment: @Sheepy I need to use surrogate pairs for using non-BMP plane characters, for which I am looking for unicode code point escape syntax.

Comment: @overexchange So BMP is a technical issue which is another question. There exists ES6 regexp [transpiler](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regexpu) - a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=ES6+unicode+regex+transpiler).  While we are at it, what are you trying to do?