# How do I remove all the Chinese characters from a string?

Tags: r, string

I am trying to remove all the Chinese characters from the following string:

```
x <- "2.87Y 1282501 12电网MTN4 AAA 4.40 /4.30* 2000、"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

I went Googling around and found [a page about Unicode character ranges](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode.php).  After looking through some of the CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) Unicode ranges, I came to the conclusion that you need to remove the following Unicode ranges if all your strings are similar to this particular string.

- `4E00-9FFF` for CJK Unified Ideographs
- `3000-303F` for CJK Symbols and Punctuation

Using `gsub()`, we can do

```
gsub("[\U4E00-\U9FFF\U3000-\U303F]", "", x)
# [1] "2.87Y 1282501 12MTN4 AAA 4.40 /4.30* 2000"
```

Data:

```
x <- "2.87Y 1282501 12电网MTN4 AAA 4.40 /4.30* 2000、"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this using `iconv`. This will remove all Non-ASCII characters including your Chinese, Japanese, Korean etc.

```
iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")
#[1] "2.87Y 1282501 12MTN4 AAA 4.40 /4.30* 2000"
```

Answer (score 3):

Chinese characters' **unicode** range is \u4E00-\u9FA5

First use `re.findall(u'[^\u4E00-\u9FA5]', string)` to get the list of non-chinese characters in the string, then scan the string and remove all the characters that not in that list.

Try this:

```py
import re
def strip_chinese(string):
    en_list = re.findall(u'[^\u4E00-\u9FA5]', string)
    for c in string:
        if c not in en_list:
            string = string.replace(c, '')
    return string
```

Comment: Please add some description to the answer explaning what the code does and why it is written as it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using unicode blocks and **stringr** package. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41155368/3980197) gives the unicode blocks, there's more than one.

```
> str_replace_all("先秦兩漢", "[\u2E80-\u2FD5\u3190-\u319f\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FCC\uF900-\uFAAD]", "")
[1] ""
```