# Match numbers before particular Chinese words

Tags: r, string, nlp, stringr

How can I use stringr to match number before particular Chinese words? For example 2020年1月4日 (4 Jan 2020)? I want to get something like this:

```
[1] 2020 1 4
```

Comment: Use `regex` module

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Does this work for you? `gsub("[\U4E00-\U9FFF\U3000-\U303F]", " ", x)` where `x` is the string from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068770/how-do-i-remove-all-the-chinese-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

It's not terribly clear what you want, unfortunately.

Do you want to use `str_match`? Then this is the correct regex_

```
string <- "2020年1月4日"
library(stringr)
str_match(string = string,
          pattern = "\\d+年\\d+月\\d+日")
#>      [,1]
#> [1,] "2020年1月4日"
```

If you want to extract a pattern which matches the regex:

```
str_extract(string = string,
            pattern = "\\d+年\\d+月\\d+日")
#> [1] "2020年1月4日"
```

Or if you just want to know if the pattern is present in your string:

```
str_detect(string = string,
           pattern = "\\d+年\\d+月\\d+日")
#> [1] TRUE
```

Did you use these commands and they are not working as expected? Then you might want to look into encoding of your string.

Does this answer your question?