# How do i detect Chinese characters in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there anyway to detect Chinese characters (Simplified or Traditional) using Postgresql?

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow[SO]`, please be a bit more specific [when asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): What have you tried so far with code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get?

Comment: I can check for non Ascii characters like this: column_name  ~ '[^[:ascii:]]'   
But i need only Chinese chars....

Comment: You should do some coding on your own and show us how far you got... We **do not** write full codes for **free!**

Comment: You can detect Chinese characters like this: **column_name**  ~ '[\x4e00-\x9fff]'

Comment: Btw i have no clue about postgresql, but i wanted to help you with building a acceptable question. But if you don't do your part, than i can't help you. See ya

Answer (score 7):

```
column_name ~ '[\x4e00-\x9fff]'
```

Comment: There are a few more unicode ranges to take into account; see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode) for details. You can put multiple ranges into the same regex character class, e.g. `column_name ~ '[\x4e00-\x9fff\x3400-\x4dbf]'`

Comment: Thanks @NickBarnes