# How do I detect Chinese characters using REGEX or a SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, chinese-locale

I'd like to detect Chinese characters in a redshift postgresql database using a SQL query.

An acceptable answer can include regex since I can use `regexp_instr`.

I think that this will detect non-English characters: `where regexp_instr(column, '[^[:print:]]') > 0`

Can I do something like that which will filter to specifically Chinese characters?

Comment: If you have a database with Chinese characters, you can try, to see if it works....

Comment: I tried the code in the question and it captures all non-English characters, like cyrillic. I'd like to focus on specifically Chinese characters

Comment: Can you please see if this pattern works for you?  `regexp_instr(column, '[\u4E00-\u9FA5]') > 0`  It works with `regexp_matches` in PostgreSQL.  Sorry I do not have any Redshift access right now.

Comment: It appears to capture Chinese characters but it's not exclusively chinese characters. I'm getting regular results like `dog` and `cat` in my output

Comment: 嘗試舉一個您想要實現的目標的例子   (try to give an example of what you will like to achieve)    and Please use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63040322/edit) to add this info to your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553953/how-do-i-detect-chinese-characters-in-postgresql

Comment: Looks like a combo of that and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode. Mind adding that as an answer so I can mark it correct?