# I want to add Icon in action property of react-native-push-notification

Tags: react-native, icons, action, react-native-push-notification

## I have given unicode but it show cross icon not a valid Icon

```
showNotification = () => {
        PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
            message: "BuzzFM is Live", 
            date: new Date(Date.now()),
            actions: '["\uf036"]',//I have given unicode but it show cross
        });
}
```

Comment: Is this unicode a Chinese character? If yes, most probably it's not valid. Here's the list of a valid Chinese chars: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode

Comment: its not a Chinese Character its just one of a font-awesome unicode

Comment: did you have any way to fix it?

Comment: Didn't have a chance to try out the solution. But I assume the string needs to know it's font family which is `font-awesome` so it can render properly

Comment: have you ever use react-native-push-notification? or other notification packages?

Comment: no, I use OneSignal `https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal` instead.