# How to select values in MySQL that do not contain a Chinese character

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried:

```
select * from table1 where HEX(col1) NOT REGEXP '^(..)*(E[4-9]))'
```

but I am still getting col1 with Chinese characters like this full entry '[动物园hello'. I need to select col1 entries that do not contain any single Chinese character like this exact full entry 'abcd'.

Comment: Provide some sample data (2-3 `HEX(col1)` values with and without Chinese characters).

Comment: Too low examples. Provide at least 2-3 wrong rows as an output of `select col1, hex(col1) from table1`, please.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode

Comment: Think about backward task - select only rows which matches valid pattern, like `where HEX(col1) REGEXP '^(\ -\~)*'$`...

Answer (score 0):

I got two way to do this but neither of those is pinpoint accurate. but still worth a shot.

```
WHERE length(col) = char_length(col)
```

but i think this only work with UTF-8.

another solution:

```
WHERE col not REGEXP '[\u4e00-\u9fa5]'
```

this should work too but depend on the extension and other chinese char unicode might need to change those range.
I believe @kmoser comment have some really detail info about this problem.
but first solution is kinda useful most of the time.